# Menu text color in dark mode in Cocoa

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, swift, colors

`NSColor` has this method:

```
NSColor.selectedMenuItemTextColor()
```

But there is no method for the normal (non-selected) menu item text color. How can I determine the menu text colour (which is currently black for normal mode, white for "dark" mode)?

I have a custom view in my menu, and it needs to use the same text colour as other menu items.

---

EDIT: I'm currently using this, but I'm hoping to find a cleaner solution for `textAttributes`:

```
let isDark = NSAppearance.currentAppearance().name.hasPrefix("NSAppearanceNameVibrantDark")
let textAttributes = [
  NSForegroundColorAttributeName: isDark ? NSColor.whiteColor() : NSColor.textColor()
]
let selectedItemTextAttributes = [
  NSForegroundColorAttributeName: NSColor.selectedMenuItemTextColor()
]
```

Comment: Did you try `textColor()` and `textBackgroundColor()` for item background?

Comment: @Astoria that would make my view a white background and black text no matter what color the menu is set to. As far as I know there are 12 different colors themes for a menu, depending on Appearance and Universal Access settings in System Preferences. I'm using that as the background color behind the text.

Answer (score 1):

The help for NSColor und `selectedMenuItemColor` links to:  see Accessing System Colors in Color Programming Topics. This chapter tells to open the Developer colors in the default color selector. There you find also a `labelColor` and a couple more which are not listed in the default interface. Maybe one of those is the one you're after.

Comment: `labelColor` is always black. I need white or black depending on the user's choice for menus.

Comment: I'm out of guess then. You got one or two support questions free at Apple. Have you ever used them? Well, I did and it was useless. But hope dies at last....

Answer (score 0):

The answer is to set the view's layer color to `NSColor.textColor()` in the viewDidAppear method. You also need to have the views `wantsLayer` set to `true`.